# Xcode 7 BETA 2 building errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, xcode7

i downloaded the Xcode 7 beta 2 and i have some problems, when i build my app in simulator, it opens simulator but it doesn't install the app, and when i build my app in my Iphone 5s (iOS 7) the app is cropped.
Here is a screen : [image: here is a screen]

this is my thread when i stop the debugging

> libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap:
>       0x19514dc98 <+0>: movn   x16, #0x1e
>       0x19514dc9c <+4>: svc    #0x80
>   ->  0x19514dca0 <+8>: ret

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Xcode 7 beta 1 and 2 release notes:

> "Xcode 7.0 beta does not support iOS 8.4 and earlier simulator runtimes."

Fortunately the 3rd beta is out now, and the release notes for this version says:

> "Xcode 7.0 beta now supports downloadable legacy simulators."

I would suggest that you [download the newest Xcode 7 beta](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/) and use that instead. That might solve some of the problems.